# ksh ignores exactly two newlines when reading from /dev/tty

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

We have a ksh script which is reading from a doing a 'while read line' with the input piped into it. At the same time we're reading user confirmation input with 'read < /dev/tty', similar to the following sketch:

```
cat interestingdata | while read line ; do
    x=$(dostuff $line)
    if [[ x -ne 0 ]] ; then
        read y < /dev/tty
        $(domorestuff $y)
    fi
    echo "done optional stuff"
done
```

All works fine for processing the lines of 'interestingdata', and for most of the reads from /dev/tty. However, on the first two iterations of the while loop, the first string + newline are ignored.

By this, I mean the user types something and presses enter, and the script doesn't progress to echo "done optional stuff". Instead, the user has to type something else and press enter again, and only then does the script proceed.

This happens only for the first two iterations of the while loop, and then everything works perfectly. Any ideas how I can fix this? I have no idea what else I can do here!

Running linux kernel 2.6.9-55.9.vm2.ELsmp with ksh93 if that helps.

Comment: What OS and what do you get from `echo ${.sh.version}`. Good luck.

Comment: echo ${.sh.version} gives: Version M 1993-12-28 q

Comment: Running linux kernel 2.6.9-55.9.vm2.ELsmp with RHEL

Comment: Is that "x=dostuff $line" a typo in the question, some ksh syntax with which I am unfamiliar, or are you really executing $line with x set to 'dostuff'?

Comment: It's a typo in the question - sorry! The real problem is in the line "read y < /dev/tty", as this is the one that is not working properly; just wanted to give some context around this, and I can't publish our real code.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, I suppose you need to post a code that simulates the real one more closely.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either "dostuff" or "domorestuff" is sometimes reading from stdin.

Try replacing "dostuff" with "dostuff < /dev/null" and "domorestuff" with "domorestuff < /dev/null" and see if the behavior changes.